# Как происходит сброс до заводских настроек в Android?

Tags: android

Интересно, что происходит во время сброса Android (или как происходит сброс) на уровне системы, например в какой последовательности происходит очистка памяти? Интересно описание самого процесса поэтапно.

**P.S.** Хочется знать для общего развития :)